# MXMLC ANT for building AIR application

Tags: ant, air, mxmlc

I'm used a script ANT, with MXMLC task to build my AIR application. The generation is oK (.swf is generated). But the xxx-app.xml is not generated too ?

```
     <mxmlc 
            file="${src.dir}/${trinity.project}.mxml"
                output="${release.dir}/${trinity-client}.swf"
                locale="fr_FR"
                static-rsls="true"
                accessible="true"
                configname="air"
                debug="false"
                failonerror="true"
                fork="true"
                optimize="true"
                maxmemory="512m">
        <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/air-config.xml" />
        <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
        <source-path path-element="${src.dir}"/>
        <use-network>true</use-network>
        <external-library-path file="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs/air/airglobal.swc" append="true"/>
        <library-path dir="${ivy.cache.dir}" append="true">
            <include name="${puremvc.lib}"/>
            <include name="${kccalendar.lib}"/>
            <include name="${as3commons.lib}"/>
        </library-path>         
    </mxmlc>
```

Have you got a solution ?

Thank you very much,

Anthony

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `adt` in the sdk folder, to make a .air package.

eg:

```
<target name="execute.air">

    <condition property="adt.name" value="adt">
        <os family="unix" />
    </condition>

    <condition property="adt.name" value="adt.bat">
        <os family="windows" />
    </condition>

    <exec executable="${FLEX_HOME}/bin/${adt.name}" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="-package" />
        <arg line="-tsa none" />
        <arg line="-storetype pkcs12" />
        <arg line="-keystore ${basedir}/keys/${APP_NAME}.p12" />
        <arg line="-storepass password" />
        <arg line="${DEPLOY_DIR}/${APP_NAME}.air" />
        <arg line="${SRC_DIR}/${APP_NAME}-app.xml" />
        <arg line="-C ${DEPLOY_DIR} ${APP_NAME}.swf" />
    </exec>

</target>
```